# Why can coworkers can see what I'm doing when I VNC in and how to fix this?

Tags: vnc, mint

My cube mate tells me that when I VPN in and use VNC, he can see what I'm doing. From a security perspective, this does not seem appropriate. How can I address this? Platform is Linux Mint + Cinnamon on the server side and Ubuntu 14.04.4 on the client side. I was doing some experimentation on what would work best. I tried x11vnc and also tightvnc along with various clients.

Comment: Set a VNC password that only you know on that system.  That way, VNC is protected by a password and then only you can reach it.  (Configuring it varies by the VNC platform in use; without more details it's impossible to give you a true answer).  Note however that Mint is offtopic - if Mint+Cinnamon is where your VNC resides, this question is not answerable on this siite.

Comment: If you mean you VNC from a location outside of the office, I think it's possible that what you're doing displays on the screen. If this is the case, look in the settings, find a secure software, or find a way to disable the display when using VNC.

Comment: That's the thing. There was a password in all cases. Isn't t the problem the display rather than access?

Comment: The problem is likely that you're using a *desktop sharing* implementation of the VNC server (such as vino-server or x11vnc) which is designed to relay the physical desktop session of the remote machine, rather than a *standalone* implementation of VNC (like vnc4server / tightvncserver).

Answer (score 0):

1.On the remote machine: install vncserver:

`sudo apt-get install vnc4server`

2. Create a second desktop that will run in the background and create a password for it:

`sudo vncserver :1`

3. Edit `$HOME/.vnc/xstartup` to look like the following using any text editor:

`#!/bin/sh`

`# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop: unset SESSION_MANAGER exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`

`#[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup`

`#[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources`

`#xsetroot -solid grey`

`#vncconfig -iconic &`

`#xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &`

4. Restart vncserver:

`sudo vncserver -kill :1`

`sudo vncserver :1`

5. Use vnc viewer to access this desktop and instead of port 5900 repleace the end digit with desktop number. E.g. to connect to 192.168.0.10 desktop :1 it would be 192.168.0.10::5901. The desktop that the user sees by default is desktop :0.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks good. I'll try it out when I get home tonight. That will be late as I'm working 10 hrs today.

Comment: @user447607 Have you tried the solution? did that work? if yes, try marking it as answered

Comment: Hard to tell. I'm aboard a "sinking ship" and as a consequence, my cubemate has already bailed so now I don't have anyone to check. ;-)